# Python doesn't realise sqlalchemy extension is installed?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, anaconda, db2

Odd question here. I recently installed the ibm_db_sa extension on a new computer through Anaconda Prompt. However, when I try to run a script that uses it I get this error message:

[image]

This looked to me as if sqlalchemy was not installed, so I tried installing it separately (again, through Anaconda Prompt). However, this just returned a message saying "*Requirement already satisfied*".

Does anyone know what's going wrong here please? This worked fine on my old computer after just installing ibm_db_sa, so I'm not quite sure why its not working now?

Answer (score 0):

This could be related to that [zxJDBC was removed from SQLAlchemy](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/issues/5094). It is in the [Changelog for 1.4](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/changelog/changelog_14.html?highlight=zxjdbc). If you installed the most recent version of SQLAlchemy, that might cause the "No module named" error.

Comment: Ah, ok. Do you know if there is either a replacement for zxJDBC or another way to install it then please? Apologies if this is a daft question - I don't really know how ibm_db_sa, sqlalchemy or zxJDBC work; I just got told I needed to install and import ibm_db_sa in order to connect to our database.

Comment: ibm_db_sa is the driver for Db2. See https://github.com/ibmdb/python-ibmdbsa/tree/master/ibm_db_sa

Comment: But I've installed ibm_db_sa. My understanding of the problem is that ibm_db_sa contains sqlalchemy, which no longer contains zxJDBC, which is a prerequisite to connect to db2; is this correct or have I misunderstood? And do you know which version of sqlalchemy was the last to have zxJDBC? According to your link I'll need to go back to an older version of sqlalchemy since I have 1.4.7 installed currently; but I'm not sure how far back I'd need to go.

Comment: ibm_db_sa is the Db2 driver for SQLAlchemy. The pip dependency management should install SQLAlchemy along with the driver. You don't need zxJDBC because the Db2 driver is based on the CLI (ODBC). I assume that you work with Db2 LUW...?

Comment: Sorry, now I'm confused. I have ibm_db_sa version 0.3.6 and sqlalchemy version 1.4.7 installed, so as you say, installing ibm_db_sa must have automatically installed sqlalchemy. However, you're saying that I don't need zxJDBC, but isn't the error message I attached saying that I do need it? I can't help on the Db2 LUW question I'm afraid; all I know is its Db2.